# Get predicted (leveled) value of y from a differenced regression in time series

Tags: regression, time-series, least-squares, econometrics, differences

Suppose I have two time series variables (x and y) which have unit root (non-stationary). I would like to regress y against x, but because they are non-stationary, I first stationarized them by differencing. So, the differences variables: diff_x and diff_y are stationary. Now, I regress as follows:

diff_y = constant + slope * diff_x

I am able to get the predicted values of diff_y, and I can invert those differences to get the leveled values.

My question: if I want to find the comparable value of y when x = 6.5, then how do I calculate from the differenced equation above?

Here, x = unemployment rate (measured in %), and y = employment to population ratio

Answer (score 0):

OK, the difference model only provides a forecast for one difference period ahead!

So, if you have monthly data, there is a one month forecast.

However, you can aggregate the data to create annual data, and therefrom derive an annual model. The corresponding difference series now can produce an annual forecast.

So, bottom line, doable but much more work involved. Also, possible consistency issues may arise. For example, explaining why there are significant differences in a model's significant variables (per the modeling estimation phase) owing to the particular data aggregation selection. Why does this occur, because model building is, in my view, not a rigorous science, there is a degree of art (as aggregation reduces degrees of freedom and forces choices on variables, etc).